# meaning of "disc" in "strewn with the white discs of morning glory"

Tags: word-meaning

[At one point we drove to an alpine meadow strewn with the white **disc**s of morning glory and bordered by ponderosa pines.](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/12/magazine/can-prairie-dogs-talk.html)

I wonder which of the following the "disc" means here :

1. round area
2. [the central part of the flower head of a typical composite made up of closely packed tubular flowers](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disc)

Comment: You might have to do some research. There are species of [morning glory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morning_glory) with white flowers, and others with white centres and coloured outsides. But morning glories do not have composite flower heads. Maybe it is a species with all white flowers - what types grow in the area where the story takes place? Also, is there a botany Stack Exchange board?

Comment: @StuartF - There are a number of white Morning Glory varieties, and I can accept 'discs' being used loosely to mean 'roundish flowers'.

Comment: @StuartF Thank you very much.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second meaning of "disk" appears fairly technical - not all dictionaries list it, and as Stuart F notes it wouldn't apply to morning glory flowers anyway.

I can't read the article, but from the title and being in NYT it seems to be a rather casual reportage. As such, I'd understand the *discs* as referring to the flowers being overall round in shape - cf. *the green triangles of spruce trees*.

Comment: Thank you very much.